# IP Tables for Yocto Krogoth

Tags: linux-kernel, iptables, yocto

I am using a imx6 platform from variscite with a yocto krogoth linux. Now I try to use the IPTables tool and there is an recipe available and I also activate the support in the kernel but I always get the following error message. Does somebody knows what i am doing wrong?!

```
modprobe: module ip_tables not found in modules.dep
iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Comment: Few pointers: Did you try `depmond`? Did you double check that `ip_tables` is built-in or available as a module? Did you check stuff from a very similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/813323/iptables-module-ip-tables-not-found-for-root ?

Comment: Have you ensured that you have installed the kernel modules to the image?

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? I'm having the same problem